# Center a UIVIEW on all device sizes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface

I am workin on an iPhone app and am relatively new to xcode.  I am trying to design my application so that no matter what device is used, the main ui will be center.  I have a uiview that contains all of my controls (textfields, submit button).  I have this uiview centered in interface builder based on the iPhone 5 simulated metrics.  When I test this on an iPhone 4 or below, naturally this uiview is not centered but towards the bottom of the screen.  Is there a simple way witin interface builder to have this uiview autocenter based on the device?  Do I need to add this in programmatically?

Thanks to anyone who can help!

iPhone 3.5inch = http://bit.ly/14r6R6U 
iPhone 4inch = http://bit.ly/WOyQcn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the auto resizing option in the interface builder. Fix the top margin and bottom margin and set flexible height

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Will this stretch the image I am using at all?  I have a ui image created for retina/non retina.?

Comment: Yup..Its work for  me. Otherwise you can use different images for retina and non retina as image.png and image@2x.png. It will automatically use them depends upon the device

Comment: I ended up unselected all of the autosizing options and the view is now centered on all iphone sizes.  (no strut or spring is red).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xcode 4.5 onward then you can make two different xibs for iPhone 3.5 inches and iPhone 4 inches like:[image]

this will easy to maintain all view components .

Comment: Thanks!  I have thought about this. To me it seems like a bit of work to maintain separate xibs for just this one uiview.  My app does use xib files, out of curiosity would this work with a storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Initially create the baseView with the size of (320,480) then add the view as subview of the baseview.

then Do like this,

```
CGRect _baseFrame=baseView.frame;
    _baseFrame.origin=CGPointMake((self.view.frame.size.width-baseView.frame.size.width)/2, (self.view.frame.size.height-baseView.frame.size.height)/2);
    baseView.frame=_baseFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have auto layout turned on (it is by default), you should center the view both horizontally and vertically, and give it a fixed height and fixed width. Once you have these, you should be able to delete any other constraints. This will keep it centered in any sized screen in portrait and landscape.

Comment: I came across auto layout when I was looking around online before posting this question. I have never used it before, the app I am creating was not originally for ios 6. I was able to turn auto layout on but was not sure the exact use for it. I now understand what you mean by constraints and will see how this works out. Thank You!

Comment: @user2023912, In the lower right corner of IB, there's a gray rounded rectangle with 3 icons. The left one allows you to center the view, and the center one lets you set the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explore these things:

The old way - Autosizing masks

The new way - Auto layout
This is enabled by default on new projects. You can turn it off by unchecking a box in the file inspector for the storyboard. Auto layout is ios6 only. Autosizing works on ios6,5,4...

Both of these provide layout engines that do not require code. With both methods you change the settings of objects in the storyboard using the size inspector.

Autolayout is Apple's strongly preferred way forward, but I would recommend trying autoresizing masks first. Autolayout allows you to exert far more control over relative positioning of objects, at the cost of far greater complexity. If you can achieve your result using autosizing, do.

[Raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) has a good guide to both.

Answer (score 0):

define its in your view controller

```
#define STATUSBAR_HEIGHT 20

#define SCREEN_HEIGHT (( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - STATUSBAR_HEIGHT)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH (( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.width)
```

And for example

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

//for example view height 100 and width 100 then

float xAxis = (SCREEN_WIDTH - 100)/2;
float yAxis = (SCREEN_HEIGHT - 100)/2;


[view setFrame:CGRectMake(xAxis, yAxis, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

And if you making view by xib, then you should use this

[image]